# How to add a webservice url or a string in Configuration section

Tags: c#, vb.net, web-services

I created a vb.net Windows Form application and it consumes  a webservice from url.

```
url = "http://localhost:1264/api/products"

request = DirectCast(WebRequest.Create(url), HttpWebRequest)

 response = DirectCast(request.GetResponse(), HttpWebResponse)
```

I want to add  the url string in Configuration Section(appConfig) and use this string in my code. How could i do this .
Please help

Comment: Depending on what you want to do, you could just right click on References and select Add Service Reference. If you're developing locally and deploying to a production site, this gets a little tricky switching between production and development references.

Comment: @Tim When i add service reference it shows an error message "Unable to open this internet site "

Comment: Let me guess - the URL you listed is only there when you debug?

Answer (score 0):

You should be add web service in window service application project

By right click on project, there is an option `Add Web refereces` like.

Then add your service what ever you want to use in this project.

Comment: When i add service reference it shows an error message "Unable to open this internet site "

Comment: First you did n't host your web service in IIS so please host it on IIS then add service url as reference.

Answer (score 0):

Can you able to browse the url in any browser?

If you could able to browse, try adding the web reference with asmx extension

Comment: I can browse the url in any browser. I created Rest webservice with WebApi. Not asmx file

Comment: We cannot add restful service as Web Reference. Maybe we could add the  url in config section and access the url using
    ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[""]

Comment: How could i add url in config section

Comment: Do you wish to add in Config section or appSettings?

If you are adding only one web service url, then its preferable to add in appSettings.

<configuration>
  
  <appSettings>
    <add key="WebServiceURL" value=""http://localhost:1264/api/products"" />
</appSettings>

While getting url,
string url=ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["WebServiceURL"];

Comment: I would add that when you get the setting, you need to add a .ToString() to the end of it, or Visual Studio is going to highlight it as an error.